Given $A, B, C, D$ in $Oxyz$ space, find $M \in CD$ such that $MA + MB$ is smallest. Why can't I use AM-GM to solve this?

In the $Oxyz$ space, consider four points $A(-1, 1, 6),$
$B(-3,-2,-4),$ $C(1,2,-1),$ $D(2,-2,0).$ Find $M \in CD$ such that $△MAB$ has the smallest perimeter.

As $AB$ is constant, the task is equivalent to finding $M$ such that $MA + MB$ is smallest.
$M\in CD$ so $M = (1 + t, 2- 4t, -1 + t).$ At this point, I could use calculus to find $t$ such that $MA + MB = \sqrt{f(t)} + \sqrt{g(t)}$ is smallest, and such $t = 0.5.$
However, I wanted to get the result faster so initially this is what I did:
$MA + MB \geq 2\sqrt{MA \cdot MB}$
So $MA + MB$ is smallest when $MA = MB \iff f(t) = g(t).$ However, this results in a different $M$ and a much greater sum of $MA + MB.$
I couldn't find what was wrong with this approach. Please help!

Apart from the issue with the AM-GM idea, if you actually wonder how to solve the problem, here is a HINT: Reflect point $B$ over the line $CD$ to obtain the point $B'$. The problem now is equivalent to identifying the point $M \in CD$ that minimizes the sum $|MA|+|MB'|$. Can you identify that point? (Drawing the figure might help a lot)

That kind of argument only works when

one of the 2 terms $(MA + MB)$ or $(MA \cdot MB)$ is constant (or somhow bounded in the right way), and
equlity of terms is possible.

Since 1) is not fullfilled, your argument is invalid. For any choice of $M$, say $M_1, M_2, \ldots$ you have
$$(M_1A + M_1B) \ge 2 \sqrt{M_1A \cdot M_1B},$$
$$(M_2A + M_2B) \ge 2 \sqrt{M_2A \cdot M_2B}$$
a.s.o. but since there is no relationship between $\sqrt{M_1A \cdot M_1B}$ and $\sqrt{M_2A \cdot M_2B}$, you cannot draw conclusions which sum is smallest.
You have taken a mental shortcut from the correct statement
"When two non-negative real numbers have a given positive product, their sum is smallest when they are equal."
to the incorrect statement
"When two non-negative real numbers are in some complicated relationship, their sum is smallest when they are equal."
In our case, the 'complicated relationship' is that the two numbers represent lengths of line segments, which is certainly not characterized by "their product" is constant.

Beautifully explained! Thank you very much!
